# How to reuse variable *definitions* in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

If I create a varaible *definition* like this:

```
variable "aws_ecs_config" {
  type = object({
    cpu               = number
    memory            = number
    ecs_image_address = string
  })
  logs = {
    type = object({
      group         = string
      region        = string
      stream_prefix = string
    })
  }
}
```

How can I reuse that definition in multiple places without copy-pasting?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple places? As in in different directories? Or something else?

Comment: Shared between different module definitions.

Comment: This is so annoying!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to re-use variable declarations in Terraform. If variables in different modules will have the same type, that type must be repeated in each module.

Terraform has a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) rather than a [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), so types themselves are not named and instead are matched/constrained by their form. When passing values between modules, we can use type constraints to create *conventions* between a family of related modules, but there is no mechanism to define a type (or declare a variable) in one place and reuse it in other places.

---

Terraform's [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html) mechanism considers any object with *at least* the attributes in the type constraint to be valid, so it's not necessary to define an exhaustive object type every time.

For example, if you define a variable with the following type:

```
object({
  name = string
})
```

The following object value is acceptable for that type constraint, because it has a `name` attribute of the correct type regardless of any other attributes it defines:

```
{
  name  = "foo"
  other = "bar"
}
```

For that reason, it can be better to limit the variable declaration in each module to only the subset of attributes that particular module actually requires, which reduces the coupling between the modules: they only need to be compatible to the extent that their attribute names overlap, and don't need to directly bind to one another.

Comment: Was limiting Terraform's type system to the structual variety a design decision to guide the use of types in a specific direction, or more of a temporary simple approach to possibly revisit later, or for some other reason?

Comment: This "feature" forces anyone wanting some nice, tightly defined data structures to repeat themselves constantly. The value of DRY seems clear, what is the advantage of WET?

Comment: Is it possible to re-use the same type declaration within the same module for multiple variables? For ex. in above example I would want to have `aws_ecs_config_xyz` & `aws_ecs_config_abc` with same type structure. Cannot use list for it as `[0]` or `[1]` would not make sense for my usecase (`[abc]` & `[xyz]` can make sense though, if I can validate the existence of indexes abc & xyz).

Comment: There is no way to re-use a type definition between two different `variable` blocks, regardless of which modules they are in. You could potentially declare a single variable as a map of objects where "abc" and "xyz" are map keys, but then you'd need to validate their presence using [a custom validation rule](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#custom-validation-rules) rather than a type constraint.

Answer (score 2):

### Workaround

This is possible without *explicit* Terraform support. (There are some discussions about types. [Weigh in](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27365) if you think it would be handy)

Terraform allows variables to be declared over multiple files, and if the modules live on a Linux filesystem, reuse is vastly simplified. (Windows folks... well, it *is* [possible](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/), just not [pretty](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29483) and may not play well with version control.)

### How?

- Move the variable definition to a file named `variable.aws_ecs_config.tf`
- Place it in a well known place. Say, a directory called `variables` that lives next to `modules`.
- Whenever the variable is needed in a module, create a symlink to the variable file: `ln -s <path/to/variables>/variable.aws_ecs_config.tf`